# Compare yyyy-mm-dd formatted date strings without the Date object possible?

Tags: javascript, date, compare

If I define a date range using purely date strings in yyyy-mm-dd format, it appears comparison will work just fine without using the `Date` object:

```js
const dateParts = '2021-12-15--2022-01-15'.split('--') // My date range
const startDate = dateParts.slice(0, 1) // '2021-12-15'
const endDate = dateParts.slice(1) // '2022-01-15'

const date = '2021-12-14'

// Test if date is within the range     
console.log(date >= startDate && date <= endDate) // false
```

Using any date in the above example will test successfully if what I want is ensure that the date I'm looking for is within the range.

Why is this working? If javascript was, under the hood, evaluating the date strings as numbers, this should not be working. Is it maybe just implicitly assuming it's a date without me having to parse them using `new Date(date)`...?

Update: I'm not looking for solutions on how to do this using the `Date` object, I'd be more interested in examples where comparing dates this way would NOT work.

Comment: A string is a string. JavaScript has no idea that your strings represent dates.

Comment: Would work the same if the string was "abc--def"

Comment: @Pointy so why is one string greater or less than another one? what is it actually calculating? alphabetical order? can you maybe give me an example of where this would actually be unsafe to use for date comparision?

Comment: Yes, alphabetical (well, character set) order. "1" is less than "2" etc.

Comment: @Pointy so "01" is less than "11", meaning, while not an "official" way, there is actually no example where this wouldn't work, irrespective of the fact this may not be the official way, or that people appear to be afraid of using it because it may not be "safe"...?

Comment: I'm not afraid of using it. Yes, string comparison works consistently.

Comment: Note you could do `let [startDate, endDate] = '2021-12-15--2022-01-15'.split('--');`. There is no reason not to use strings for relational comparisons (`>`, `<`, `==`, etc.) if the dates are in ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @RobG post this answer and I'll accept it as the correct one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works (Or if it looks like its working) because its just a basic [string comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#comparing_strings) and ***not the date comparison.*** To do a proper date comparison, you need to do the proper string to date conversion, and then compare them.

```js
const dateParts = '2021-12-15--2022-01-15'.split('--') // My date range
const startDate = dateParts[0] // '2021-12-15'
const endDate = dateParts[1] // '2022-01-15'

const startDateArray = startDate.split("-").map(element => parseInt(element));
const endDateArray = endDate.split("-").map(element => parseInt(element));

const date = '2022-01-15'
const dateArray = date.split("-").map(element => parseInt(element));

// Test if date is within the range     
console.log(new Date(dateArray[0], dateArray[1] - 1, dateArray[2]) >= new Date(startDateArray[0], startDateArray[1] - 1, startDateArray[2]) && new Date(dateArray[0], dateArray[1] - 1, dateArray[2]) <= new Date(endDateArray[0], endDateArray[1] - 1, endDateArray[2])) // false
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to compare dates using the `Date` object, I'm looking to understand why my comparision works. If anything, if you could give me an example of where it would not work, that would help...

Comment: Got it. There is an official documentation on what you are exactly asking and how it works. I have updated the answer with the link.

Comment: @benomatis Numeric string comparisons are tricky and not always intuitive as they are lexical not numeric comparisons. Try `console.log("20">"100")` . It is unexpectedly true

Comment: Here's a good read https://javascript.info/comparison

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not comparing "20"<"100", am I? This is a very strict format, I'm asking this specific question, for this specific situation - can you give me a date range and a date, expressed in this format, that would NOT follow this rule and return an incorrect boolean...?

Comment: @benomatis Maybe not but still safer to do date object comparison IMO

Comment: @charlietfl if it works in every scenario, why is it not safe...?

Comment: @benomatis I trust the date object better is all without running a bunch of string tests to be absolutely certain. There may not be any string cases that fail

Comment: @Deepak by the way, why so complicated? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just wrap `startDate`, `endDate` and `date` inside `new Date(variable)`?

Comment: There are so many parse issues when it comes to date in JavaScript. And so many different solutions. I just gave you a very simple and clean one. Your suggestion works obviously.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to change the strings to Dates for comparison. A major reason for the ISO 8601 format is that dates compare (`<`, `>`, `==`, etc.) and sort correctly as strings. One comparison you can do with a string but not a Date is `dateA == dateB`. For Dates you need to cast to primitive first, e.g. `+dateA == +dateB`.

Answer (score -3):

This should solve your problem

```
const dateParts = '2021-12-15--2022-01-15'.split('--'); // My date range
const startDate = dateParts[1]; // '2021-12-15'
const endDate = dateParts[0]; // '2022-01-15'

const date = '2021-12-10'

// Test if date is within the range     
alert(date < startDate && date < endDate)
```

Comment: Solve it how? You completely changed the range check in a way that makes no sense. As for the indexing of dateParts the values will be identical if you use OP's slice() approach